# Unordered type error: int stored as string

Tags: python, string, int

I'm looping through a file to find the highest value and then return the value and number of lines. If I didn't convert `myMax` with `int()` I would get an unordered type error with the variable set as a string. What did I forget?!

```
def main():
    myMax= 0
    myCount = 0

    myFile = open("numbers.dat", 'r')
    for line in myFile :
        myCount = myCount + 1
        if int(line) > int(myMax): 
            myMax = line

    myFile.close()

    print ("Out of %s lines, the highest value found was %s" %(myCount, myMax))

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `myMax = line` to `myMax = int(line)`. This will also make `if int(line) > int(myMax):` convertable to `if int(line) > myMax:`

Comment: Could you pass along why this happens? I'm guessing it's something with compiling since `myMax` is initialized as an `int` and assigned later as a string, correct?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you initialize it. However, it does start out as an int, and then later is changed to a string, which does not compare the way you would like.

Answer (score 0):

This your file contains valid numbers and not strings that can't be converted to numbers.

```
with open('numbers.dat') as f:
   lines = [int(line) for line in f if line.strip()]

print 'Out of %s lines, the highest value is %s' % (len(lines),max(lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the line 'myMax = line' cause it - you made type conversion(if int(line) > int(myMax):) but not assigned it. Wht if:

```
def main():
    myMax = 0
    with open("numbers.dat", 'r') as myFile:
        for i, line in enumerate((int(x) for x in myFile)):
            if line > myMax: 
                myMax = line

    print ("Out of %s lines, the highest value found was %s" % (i, myMax))

main()
```

In a case you have empty lines and want to skip them:

```
def main():
    myMax = 0
    with open("numbers.dat", 'r') as myFile:
        for i, line in enumerate((int(x) for x in myFile if x)):
            if line > myMax: 
                myMax = line

    print ("Out of %s lines, the highest value found was %s" % (i, myMax))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to solve your problem if your "numbers.dat" file has strings and numbers throughout the file. I had to break down the lines character by character and then build up any numbers that were of multiple digits into a string variable myTemp, then whenever there is not character that is a number I checked the size of myTemp and if there was anything in it make it into an integer and assign it to myInt, reset the myTemp variable back to empty (so if there is another number on the line it won't add to the number already there), and then compare it to the current Max. It's a couple ifs but I think it does the job.

```
def is_number(s):
try:
    float(s)
    return True
except ValueError:
    return False
```

def main():

```
myMax= 0
myCount = 0
myTemp = ''
lastCharNum = False

myFile = open("numbers.dat", 'r')
for line in myFile :
    myCount = myCount + 1
    for char in line: #go through each character on the line
        if is_number(char) == False:  #if the character isnt a number
            if len(myTemp) == 0:   #if the myTemp is empty  
                lastCharNum = False #set lastchar false
                continue #then continue to the next char
            else:      #else myTemp has something in it
                myInt = int(myTemp)#turn into int
                myTemp = '' #Flush myTemp variable for next number (so it can check on same line)
                if myInt > myMax: #compare
                    myMax = myInt

        else:# otherwise the char is a num and we save it to myTemp

            if lastCharNum:
                myTemp = myTemp + char
                lastCharNum = True #sets it true for the next time around
            else:
                myTemp = char
                lastCharNum = True #sets it true for the next time around

myFile.close()

print ("Out of %s lines, the highest value found was %s" %(myCount, myMax))
```

main()

If the "numbers.dat" file has only numbers on each line then this solves it pretty easy:

```
def main():
myMax= 0
myCount = 0

myFile = open("numbers.dat", 'r')
for line in myFile :
    myCount = myCount + 1
    if int(line) > myMax: #compare
        myMax = int(line)

myFile.close()

print ("Out of %s lines, the highest value found was %s" %(myCount, myMax))
```

main()